# Is it safe to put a hibernated hard disk to an external casing?

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs, hibernate

Last night I hibernated my laptop, only to find out in the morning that it cannot be turned on again (power light is off even when the adapter is plugged in). Long story short, I have tried many ways and I suppose I can't make it on again.

But my important data is in the hard disk. I need the data for my work.

I plan on pulling out the hard disk from the laptop, and putting it to an external casing (to turn it into an external HDD). Then I could retrieve my data with my desktop computer. But I'm not sure. I'm afraid doing so will break the hard disk, since it was hibernated from the last usage.

Could I proceed or I need to think of other way? And additional question: what would happen if  it is accessed from my desktop computer?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  `ntfs-3g` on linux will detect if the volume contains hibernation data and refuse to mount it without a force flag for this reason.  The reason for this is that the hibernated system assumes the disk has not been modified while it was hibernated, and may still cache data in its hibernation image, which would be rendered invalid by any modifications another system does to the disk during hibernation.

Of course, if you *can't* resume the system ever, then you don't have to worry about this, and the recommended work around in `ntfs-3g` is to delete the hibernation file to make sure the system can not be resumed after you tamper with it.  As long as you don't try to resume the hibernated system, then accessing it from another system is no different than if you had lost power; at worst a `chkdsk` is needed.

Comment: I apologize for my inexpediency, but what is a NTFS-3G and how to use it to delete the hibernation file? Could it be used with Windows XP? (my dekstop computer is also a XP)

Comment: @deathlock NTFS-3G has nothing to do with it. It was only used as an example third-party driver. What psusi meant is that the volume is now dirty and you MUST use `chkdsk /f` before doing anything with it.

Comment: I would assume that any dirty pages are written do disk before hibernation. Any data from applications that are modifying files will probably be in the hibernation file, but I don't think it's unsafe to force-mount in terms of finding the filesystem in a sane state. Do you have facts suggesting otherwise?

Comment: @psusi: `ntfs-3g` has nothing to do in this case, the OP is using **Windows**. Care to give a **relevant** answer?

Comment: @kinokijuf: how do I do `chckdsk` if I could not turn on the laptop? Does it mean I should do it from my desktop computer - hence it is safe to plug in my laptop's hard disk as an external HDD?

Comment: @TFM, as kinokijuf explained, it was an example of a third-party driver.  Dirty pages are flushed to disk on hibernate, but clean pages are restored when you resume, and assumed to still be correct.  That assumption is wrong if you modified the disk out from under the hibernated system, which to its mind, had the disk mounted the whole time.

Comment: @deathlock, as I said in my answer, if you aren't going to ever resume the hibernated system, then it is safe.  Just make sure you don't resume the hibernated system after ( if Windows tries to, be quick and hit the key to stop it and force it to delete the hibernation data ).

Comment: @deathlock no, it isn’t safe, but it’s dead anyway, so you’re not risking anything. You should do a `chkdsk /f` **immediately** after plugging the drive into your desktop pc.

Comment: Ok, I tried to plug it in the PC. However before I could do a chckdsk it says "Problem in detecting hardware" and soon followed by a weird sound from the hard disk. I plug off the disk immediately before it continues making weird sound. But I haven't dared to plug it in again. Is it still okay to retry? I mean, will any data be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is taking your session and saving it to the hard drive (vs. standby, saving your session to RAM) before power to the system is put to very low power mode.

You can remove the drive without damaging it or contents to put into an external drive.

CAUTION - All power (battery and plug charger) need to be removed prior. It would probably be wise to hold down the power button for 20 seconds as well after power devives are pulled.

Then remove the drive and install to appropriate external enclosure. Be sure to match the HDD type (IDE or SATA) connection for the external.

Comment: Hmm. OP states "I plan on pulling the hard disk from laptop, and putting it into an external casing. Did I miss guide the op? I am willing to edit (or have an edit done to improve the relevence to the question)...;)

Comment: Hmm does it mean this implies it is safe to proceed?